# Using term-by-term Integration to solve Laplace Transforms

Tags: complex-analysis

I am attempting to use term by term integration to find the LaPlace transform of $$u(t) = \frac{\sin(t)}{t}H(t)$$  The Laplace transform is going to be $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)e^{-st}}{t}$.  Every series that I try to come up with for this function is an unrecognizable mess.  How do I approach this problem?  Or do I misunderstand what term-by-term integration is and don't even need a series?